# How to implement a page slide effect on iOS

Tags: ios, animation, gesture, epub

I am creating an ePub reader, which reads ePub files. I want to implement a page slide effect similar to a physical book. [For example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jy8vLAzyecE).

What animation is this? This doesn't work:

```
- (void)loadPage{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    //change to set the time 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1]; 
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; 
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES]; 

    // do your view swapping here 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

on swipe:

```
- (void)swipeRightAction:(id)ignored
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe Right");
    if (_pageNumber>0) {

        _pageNumber--;
        [self loadPage];
    }

}

- (void)swipeLeftAction:(id)ignored
{
    NSLog(@"Swipe Left");

    if ([self._ePubContent._spine count]-1>_pageNumber) {

        _pageNumber++;
        [self loadPage];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same with  third party api. You can take refrence from below URL

https://github.com/jemmons/PageCurl

https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl

https://github.com/brow/leaves

Comment: direct animation is not available ? like `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`

Comment: I didn't found such one,  you have to write custom one.